# Using git log -L to track a specific line of code forward through commits

Tags: git

I have a simple git repository (origin/master branch) with a single file **foo.java**. In the file I have a bunch of code and a specific variable `int value = 10` on line 10. The initial commit has ID **x**.

After 1 change and commit of the code, `int value = 10` moves down to line 12, commit ID **y**.

After a second change and commit, the variable changes to 20 and moves down to line 13, commit ID **z**.

Running `git log -L 13,13:foo.java` allows me to track the changes of `int value` backwards through **z**->**y**->**x**. However this is reliant on `int value` being present in the most recent commit **z**.
What I want to know is how to track the changes of `int value` forwards, starting from the initial commit **x**->**y**->**z**. That way if `int value` was removed from the code in a future commit, I will be able to know.

I have already tried `git log -L 10,10:foo.java x..origin/master` (source: [Git log -L going forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246347/git-log-l-going-forward)) to try track line 10 of the initial commit **x** forwards, but it will only look at line 10 of the latest commit **z**, no matter if I checkout to commit **x** beforehand or not.

If a 3rd commit **q** was added where `int value` is removed, I want to be able to use `git log` to see that it was introduced in commit **x** and changed in commits **y** and **z** before being removed in **q**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git log -L going forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246347/git-log-l-going-forward)

Comment: @phd updated question to clarify different solution needed - as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246347/git-log-l-going-forward only allows looking at a line of the most recent commit and not a previous commit.